# Flutter issue with init and provider

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management, bloc

I have an issue with the provider pattern, I have a solution to my problem i just wanted to check its a good method and if there a better alternates.

I am trying to update the text controllers text when they first load the widget to have the value stored in my provider state. Originally, I just created the text controller in the init and just loaded the state in the build method and set the controllers text.

This was working until i wanted to have some validation of the content that would prevent certain things being passed into the state ( for example preventing empty strings).

```
textController.addListener(() {

         if( RULE ABOUT WHETHER TO SET STATE BASED ON TEXT){
            state.textField = textController.text;         
          }
    });
```

The problem arose here, as they user would delete their word and this would fail the rule. The rebuild would occur (as they had pressed a key) and the text.controller would then rebuild to what was in the state (a single letter as it failed the rule). Effectively this prevented them from deleting, which is something i want them to be able to do but for this not to update the state.

I found this library https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout which allows a method to be overridden which is called once immediately after the build.

My solution uses this by creating the text controller in the initstate. 
Assigning it to the TextField in the build.

Then creating a local field that would maintain the textField widget string content.

Then in the new afterbuild method i would assign whats on the state to the variable and update the text controllers text to have this value.

Then in the text.controllers text changed listener I used my rule to only update this state if it met the rule. Therefore if they deleted content they shouldn't be able to and closed/reopened the widget the state would rebuild to still have a valid value.

Is using this library a good solution to this or is there a better technique?

---------------- EDIT

Sorry for my wordy first part. I think my main question is just how am i meant to init Controllers if the data i need has to come from the state in the build.

For example.

```
// This must go in the build as it requires state
myTabsController = TabController(length: myState.list.length, vsync: this);
```

I'm initialisng the controller every time it builds now... How am i meant to put this in the init but still access the state variables.

(I've tried using the afterFirstLayout() callback from the AfterLayoutMixin but that just causes more problems.

Feel free to ask me to clarify more. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you simplify your problem? Just tell what you want to achieve. You know programmers love terse explanations :) Share more code less comment if possible.